# Joystick intercalate with camera rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine

I make game with fps , when I rotate the camera the joystick doesn't work properly. I have a fixed Joystick , when I try to move by rotation anything in movement change . Do I need to change the joystick ? or do I need to change something in the script for the camera rotation ? When I start the game on the mobile , the rotation affects the joystick . When I move the joystick forward and do some rotation , forward becomes backward , left right , if I move right the rotation , right becomes backward , etc . what can I do

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[AddComponentMenu("Camera-Control/Mouse Look")]
public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{

    public enum RotationAxes { MouseXAndY = 0, MouseX = 1, MouseY = 2 }
    public RotationAxes axes = RotationAxes.MouseXAndY;
    public float sensitivityX = 15F;
    public float sensitivityY = 15F;

    public float minimumX = -360F;
    public float maximumX = 360F;

    public float minimumY = -60F;
    public float maximumY = 60F;

    float rotationY = 0F;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            float turnAngleChange = (touch.deltaPosition.x / Screen.width) * sensitivityX;
            float pitchAngleChange = (touch.deltaPosition.y / Screen.height) * sensitivityY;

            // Handle any pitch rotation
            if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseXAndY || axes == RotationAxes.MouseY)
            {
                rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY + pitchAngleChange, minimumY, maximumY);
                transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, transform.localEulerAngles.y, 0f);
            }

            // Handle any turn rotation
            if (axes == RotationAxes.MouseXAndY || axes == RotationAxes.MouseX)
            {
                transform.Rotate(0f, turnAngleChange, 0f);
            }
        }

        void Start()
        {
            //if(!networkView.isMine)
            //enabled = false;

            // Make the rigid body not change rotation
            //if (rigidbody)
            //rigidbody.freezeRotation = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "it doesn't work properly" makes it sound like it doesn't compile. Please be more descriptive.

Comment: It's ok now @Ruzihm?

Comment: Try multiplying `deltaPosition.x` and `deltaPosition.y` by `-1f` to have the directions flip